# Debian 8 Jessie and NVIDIA drivers

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, nvidia, gpu

I am in the process of installing Debian 8.0 on a laptop with NVIDIA graphics cards.

After a successful installation and reboot I use [this guide](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers) to install the proprietary NVIDIA drivers; essentially I run the following steps:

- Add "contrib" and "non-free" repositories,
- `# aptitude update`,
- `# aptitude -r install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') nvidia-kernel-dkms`,
- `# nvidia-xconfig`,
- Reboot.

After a reboot I see the boot splash screen and select the kernel; it continues to boot for a little while (writes text to the screen) and then the screen goes black. The PC fans start to run on high speed and after approximately 10 seconds the PC shuts down.

This has failed using Gnome, Cinnamon and Xfce. I suspect the NVIDIA drivers are not loaded properly... Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: FYI:  you don't have to explicitly install a headers package and the DKMS package; just install `nvidia-driver`.